# Solving an exponential expression, given an equation

Tags: contest-math

I am struggling to solve this question, Suppose $$2^x = 6$$, what is the value of $$2^{3x-1}$$ ?

```
I simply do not know where to start. Please note that I am expected to do this with knowledge up to Algebra 1 for this problem was found in an AMC 8 / Mathcounts Prep book.
```

Comment: Hint: $a^{bc + d} = a^{bc} \cdot a^d = (a^{b})^{c} \cdot a^d$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're looking for $2^{(3x-1)}$ in terms of $2^x$. Calculators are not allowed on the AMC 8 and finding the exact value of the logarithm would be hard to do with algebra 1 knowledge.

Recall that $2^{(3x-1)}$ is the same as $2^{(3x)}*2^{(-1)}$ since multiplying numbers of a common base yields that common base raised to the sum of the exponents, which in this case is $3x-1$. Notice again, that we can rewrite $2^{(3x)}$ as ${2^x}^{(3)}$. Now, we have in all, $${2^x}^{(3)}*2^{(-1)}$$

Just apply the fact that $2^{x}=6$ here and substitute. We are left with $6^3*2^{-1}$. This is equal to $216*.5$ which is $108$.

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$ 2^{3x-1}=\frac{(2^x)^3}{2}=\frac{6^3}{2}=108 $$